# PHP if isset issues

Tags: php, isset

I only want to echo output only when 'death_date' has a value. This is my code:

```
<?php if (isset($term_data['death_date'])): ?>
    <li>
        <label><?php echo esc_html__('Deceased on:'); ?></label>
        <span><?php echo esc_attr($term_data['death_date']); ?></span>
    </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

However this code still outputs 'Deceased on:' whether 'death_date' has a value or not. What am i doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: result of `var_dump($term_data['death_date']));` ? I suspect this is an empty string

Comment: where did you get $term_data? from database?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
if (!empty($term_data['death_date'])){

}
```

Comment: Yes that did it! Thanx alot!

Comment: Welcome dear 

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 if (!empty($term_data['death_date'])){

 }
```

OR this:

```
if ($term_data['death_date'] ?? null){

}
```